# Why do the family members of the President involve in politics

Tags: united-states, president, donald-trump, constitution

The President is elected not his family then why the family members of the president  take part in politics and take part and make speeches in not all but many political  meetings.I'm not talking about the First Lady but people like  Ivanka Trumpetc, etc... Isn't this discrimination? They don't have the right because the people didn't elect them. Does the Constitution state anything about this?

Comment: "Isn't this discrimination?" What? Against whom?

Comment: It is nepotism, which our system fails to resolve

Comment: This is not something that is generally practiced, certainly not to the extent that it is under the current administration.  As for why it's done in the current administration, that would involve the psychology of the current President.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are thousands of roles that each president appoints. By definition, none of those people were elected. Would you prefer each of those were also elected? How big would that ballot be?

Trump is only unusual in not caring there is the appearance of nepotism.

Comment: Why, other Republicans can also be appointed by him, instead of his son or daughter

Comment: @JoeBiden because he wants who he wants, and it is within his power to do so.

Comment: Is there no appeal to Supreme Court to end nepotism

Comment: @JoeBiden No, that's up to the electorate to decide